# WPF MediaElement, change decoder

Tags: wpf, mediaelement

Is it possible to configure MediaElement for changing decoder for certain av stream? for example, you've installed two different h264 decoders one is free and another is commercial, your program can just use free one.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this programmatically through MediaElement.  It uses the Windows Media Player OCX control which in turn is using MediaFoundation to decode.  There's an app out there that lets you choose which containers MediaFoundation should attempt to decode, so you can potentially override MediaFoundation with something like ffdshow.  Theoretically you could utilize the same methodology but it would be a system-wide change.